# How To Access Course Material In Google Classroom API?

Tags: google-classroom

Using the [Google Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork) is there a way to get or create **Material** for **Courses**?

[image: Coursework Types]

I'm able to get a listing of **Assignments** and **Questions** but not **Material** using [courses.courseWork](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork).

Answer (score 1):

### Unfortunately so far it's not possible

However, a related
[feature request](https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/115421140) has been filed on Google's Public Issue Tracker and quite a few users have indicated that they are interested in the feature.

Show that you are also interested by giving a "star" to this feature request, this will show the importance of the feature and you will be updated about its implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll follow that feature request for updates.